# Javascript - extract page url and get path name

Tags: javascript

My URL will be like:   [www.test.com/element/test1.html](http://www.test.com/element/test1.html)

From this URL, I need to extract the pathname anything before *.html.
In this example, I need to get "element". Likewise dynamically.

But, the below code extracts only "test1.html"

```js
var current_path = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
console.log('Current path: ', current_path);
```

Comment: `pop` removes the last element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you get test1.html because .pop() return the element that is going outside of the array so

```
var current_path = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

is not a good idea, but you could try this instead

```
const allPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
const current_path = allPath[/*the index you want, if it's the first then use 0*/]
```

Comment: Thanks @saren. I need to total array value - 1 to get "element" value as per my example?

Answer (score -1):

You want second element, not the last one. When you log the result of the split, you will get following array:

```js
[
  "", // zero element
  "element", // 1st element
  "test1.html" // 2nd element, and pop gives you the last element in array, which is this one
]
```

```js
var current_path = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
console.log('Current path: ', current_path);
```